# Linear Equations question from the Common Admission Test (India)

Tags: linear-algebra

This question is in the prescribed syllabus of Common Admission Test which is an aptitude exam, conducted across India for admission into postgraduate management programmes of premier management institutes of the country.

A car rental agency has the following terms. If a car is rented for 5 hr or less, then, the charge is Rs. 60 per hour or Rs. 12 per kilometre whichever is more. On the other hand, if the car is rented for more than 5 hr, the charge is Rs. 50 per hour or Rs. 7.50 per kilometre whichever is more. Akil rented a car from this agency, drove it for 30 km and ended up playing Rs. 300. For how many hours did he rent the car?
A) 4 hr
B) 5 hr
C) 6 hr
D) None of these

## LinearEquation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C) 6 hours.

30km at first rate gives Rs.360, so the car is rented for more than 5 hours.

30km at second rate gives Rs.225, so the charge must be per hour. $\frac{300}{50}=6.$

Comment: could you please be a little more clear? Thanks!

Comment: @ShahbaazSheikh We know that the car has been driven 30km and the charge is Rs.300, so if the car was rented for 5 hours or less it would cost Rs.12 per km. Per km this would cost in total Rs.360, more than the cost for 5 hours (Rs.300) so the total charge would be Rs.360 as this is more than charge from the hourly rate. Now we know that the car is rented more than 5 hours. We can now easily check the charge for the number of km at the second rate, Rs.225; notably less than Rs.300. Therefore the car must be charged by the hour. To cost Rs.300 the car must have been rented for 6 hours.

Comment: many thanks for the explanation!